# Unable to access external hard disk "unknown filesystem type 'exfat'"

Tags: mount, exfat

> Error mounting systems managed device `/dev/sdb1`:
>
> Command-line `mount"/mnt/5617-A6EF"` exited with non-zero exit status
>
> ```
> 32:mount:mnt/5617-A6EF:unknown filesystem type 'exfat'.
> ```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed xfat utillities ? `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` from a terminal should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the error:

```
unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

This means that you don't have the exfat file system installed.

To install exfat, do:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

You should now be able to mount your external HDD.

Also, you might need to reboot your PC for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Reboot, seriously? Why? Not running an old Windows here

Comment: no we are not , I came across the awnser when looking for something else and posted that awnser from previous fix

Comment: Usually a `modprobe` might be all that's required, or user logging out & back in if it's a desktop related change. Upgrading the kernel is even possible without rebooting.